# SQL WEEK NUMBER

Tags: sql, calendar, week-number

I am looking for a way to extract a week number based on this calendar:
http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custom.html?year=2014&country=1&wno=1&holm=1&df=1

so eg a date of '2014-12-28 00:00:00.000' should give me week 1 and not 53
SELECT DATEPART (wk,'2014-12-28 00:00:00.000') gives 53

please note that this is not always the same as ISO WEEK

any idea?

Kris

Comment: What database are you using? The answer will likely depend on that.

Comment: What's "this calendar" about and how does it differ from ISO week? Please help with a better description.

Comment: the calendar that I am using is a US calendar

the query below shows you an example

select
datepart(iso_week, '2013-12-29 00:00:00.000'), -- it gives you 52
datepart(week, '2013-12-29 00:00:00.000'),-- it gives you 53
1 as whatineed

week number 1 comes from 
http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custom.html?year=2013&country=1&wno=1&holm=1&df=1

I am using SLQ SERVER 2012

Comment: http://weeknumber.net/?q=2014-12-29 

this is the logic that I need to incorporate in my code

I would greatly appreciate some help :)